# 0000-00-00 as date in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have to build a Laravel application on an existing (old) database. This database uses 0000-00-00 as default dates. There is no way I can change this because the current system (which will also be kept) uses this to check if something is active for an infinite amount of time (for example: `active_from` 0000-00-00 & `active_till` 0000-00-00 means it's always active).

I want to add a column to an existing table, so I created a migration: `add_columnname_to_tablename_table`. In the `up()` function I did: `$table->string('columnname')`. When I run the migration, I get:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column `active_from` at row 1.

The old system is too big to make any changes to this -- and I'm not allowed to change it.

Is there any way to make Laravel accept 0000-00-00 as a valid date(time)?

Comment: You can use string if default value otherwise date format

Comment: disabling`NO_ZERO_DATE` sql_mode might help for your connection session by running a query `SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@sql_mode. ',NO_ZERO_DATE'. '');` before running the insert

Comment: change all the date to correct date value and set default value as current_value or some valid value

Answer (score 6):

Laravel uses strict mode by default, I have fixed this by changing `strict => true` in `config/database.php` to `strict => false`.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime will return a number below zero when the date is invalid such as common in MySQL 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Make sure you pass an object type date or carbon:

```
  return strtotime(date or carbon object) < 0 ? null : date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a MySql issue, as zero dates are disabled for newer versions of MySql. In addition, the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode was deprecated (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). To get around this, you could change all zero dates in your database to the unix epoch time `1970-01-01 00:00:00` (which is what I had to do with mine after upgrading MySql).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to first set the SQL column type to `TIMESTAMP` and then when storing data use date() inbuilt php function

```
$myModel->my_date = date('y-m-d');
```

it will save in proper format just like `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Example data when saved:

```
"start_date": "2021-08-14 00:00:00",
```